# custom checkbox is not working in IE10

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox

i need to create one custom checkbox with green checkmark

i wrote following code :

```
<input id="Text1" type="text" style="width:150px" tabindex="1" />    
    <input id="Text2" type="text" style="width:150px" tabindex="2" />
    <label class="myCheckbox" tabindex="3" contenteditable='true'>
        <input type="checkbox" name="test"/>
        <span></span>
    </label>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" style="width:150px" tabindex="4" />
```

and css :

```
.myCheckbox input {
    display: none;
}
.myCheckbox span {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
    background: gray;           
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.myCheckbox input:checked + span {
    background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfplA.png") no-repeat center gray;
}
.myCheckbox {
     /*outline:none;*/
     display:inline-block;   
     font-size:0;
}

.myCheckbox:focus > span {
     /*border:2px dotted green; */
}
```

it is working fine in Google Chrome, but **IE 10**, i am not able check on checkbox

any idea ,

please get my whole code here : http://jsfiddle.net/wfk9Y/ and run in **IE10.**

Comment: i am talking about IE 10 :) sir

Answer (score 2):

I've changed `contenteditable="true"` to `contenteditable="false"` and it worked for me (tested with IE 10 and IE 11).

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wfk9Y/1/)

```
<label class="myCheckbox" tabindex="3" contenteditable='false'>
```

**EDIT**

[**DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/wfk9Y/5/)

**HTML**

```
<input id="Text1" type="text" style="width:150px" tabindex="1" />

<input id="Text2" type="text" style="width:150px" tabindex="2" />

<!-- wrap your 'checkbox' in a *div* element -->
<div class="myCheckbox" tabindex="3" contenteditable='false'>
<input type="checkbox" name="test"/>
<span></span>
</div>

<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" style="width:150px" tabindex="4" />
```

**CSS**

```
//do not set display:none as the input won't be able to receive focus
//instead, set its opacity to 0, position it absolutely, so it's not visible but tabbable

.myCheckbox input {
    opacity:0; 
    position:absolute;
    top:0
}

.myCheckbox span {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
    background: gray;           
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.myCheckbox input:checked + span {
    background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfplA.png") no-repeat center gray;
}

.myCheckbox {
    /*outline:none;*/
    display:inline-block;   
    font-size:0;
    position:relative; /*you also need to give relative positioning
                       to the parent of your input element, which will allow us to 
                       absolutely position the input*/
}

.myCheckbox:focus > span {
     /*border:2px dotted green; */
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Added `Javascript` code, when the input is clicked or `Enter` key is pressed it will check or uncheck depending on the current state of the `input` button.

[**FULL DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wfk9Y/14/)

**Javascript**

```
function attach(element,listener,ev,tf){

if(element.attachEvent) {

    element.attachEvent("on"+listener,ev);

}else{

    element.addEventListener(listener,ev,tf);

}

}

 function checkuncheck(){

 span = checkbox.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];

    if(checked == false){

        checked = true;

    span.style.background = "url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfplA.png') no-repeat center gray";

    }else{

        checked = false;

    span.style.background = "url('') no-repeat center gray";

    }

}

var checkbox = document.getElementById('customcheckbox');
var checked = false;

attach(checkbox,'keydown',function(event){

evt = event || window.event;

key = evt.which || evt.keyCode;

if(key == 13){

  checkuncheck();

 }

},false);

attach(checkbox,'click',function(event){

checkuncheck();

},false);
```

Comment: and i cannot continue with this error , cause i need use lots of jquery

Comment: That error means the library you are using is undefined, which may mean that you aren't loading `jQuery` or there is an error while loading it. Basically, it can be any error related to loading the aforementioned library.

Comment: if i set contenteditable='true' , it is working fine ! how come :(

Comment: I don't have any errors when testing my example. There is something wrong with how you load your `jQuery`.

Comment: after seting this : contenteditable='false' , i lost of tab on checkbox , in google chrome, IE 10 tab order is working fine!, still not 100 % fixed :)

Comment: I don't understand you. You mean, your checkbox isn't tabbable any more or when you hit the `Enter` key it's not getting selected?

Comment: open on Google Chrome > http://jsfiddle.net/wfk9Y/1/ > press tab on 2 textbox, 3rd tab should be at CHECKBOX !

Answer (score 0):

You should make change as below coz u need to make contenteditable="true" to contenteditable="false"

```
<label class="myCheckbox" tabindex="3" contenteditable='false'>
```

for more information :-

http://help.dottoro.com/lhwqtkhj.php

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with input checkboxes while using JQuery on Internet Explorer
The code below seems to fix the issue!

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test" style="opacity:1" />
```

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out code. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @Rob Sorry sir. I was in a hurry and not thinking.